# Single Sign On Java as Authorization and Drupal 7 as Resources With Oauth2 Concept

Tags: java, drupal

kindly need help to create Single Sign On system.
First application use Java platform with Spring Boot & Spring Security. And then second application use Drupal 7.
Flow :
First time, login into java application we call it X. Then at X have a link to direct into Drupal 7 or we call it Y. After you login at X then you click link, the page automatically redirect into page at Y.
The condition, you cannot directly hit the url at Y. Because you must login first.